# How can i write a code in html and css for the below input field along with label

Tags: html, css, forms

[image]
How can I write code in HTML and CSS for the below input field along with the label?
Please help me to achieve the above one.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tripType">What are you looking for?</label>
  <select class="select" type="select" id="tripType" placeholder="Backpacking Trips" name="tripType">
    <option value="Backpacking Trips">Backpacking Trips</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Provide suggestions to do it. I'm new to it.

Comment: You tagged this as CSS but you don't seem to have added any CSS. Please attempt this yourself first - there are many online tutorials available for free regarding styling input/select fields.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a label which border encompasses the input (select box) with a border (that does not transpares beneath the text) would be to use a [`<fieldset>` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) and its `<legend>` tag:

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #5c819c;
}

fieldset select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #5c819c;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>What are you looking for?</legend>
  <select class="select" type="select" id="tripType" placeholder="Backpacking Trips" name="tripType">
    <option value="Backpacking Trips">Backpacking Trips</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

I Made a quick one for ya, I hope it helps:

```
  <label for="options">Backpacking Trips</label>
  <select id="options" name="options">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).